# Event after DOM manipulation in Sencha Touch

Tags: dom, mobile, extjs, web, sencha-touch-2

Is their an event available after DOM manipulation in Sencha Touch has succeeded?

I want to measure the time it takes to render a list with 1000 elements.
Therefor,  a timer is started when the list is initialized and stoppend when the list is painted like so:

```
listeners: {
 initialize: function () {
   start = new Date();
   var store = Ext.getStore('Songs');
   for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
      store.add({id: i});
    }
 },
 painted: function () {
   stop = new Date();
   Ext.Msg("Timer", stop - start);
 }
}
```

The painted event is triggerd before DOM manipulation so the 1000 listitems are not visible when the rentertime pops up.
Is there an other event that is triggerd after DOM has been manipulated and the list is updated?
Or is there an alternative method to measure the time it takes to do this?

Greets,
Sander Van Loock

Comment: Ext.dataview.component.ListItemView --> painted event ?

Comment: And if you are working with list, you might be only working with <number of Listitems visible> + 1 (infinite:true). Usually only stores with localstorage and not infinite lists become slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you are not answering, therefore I can only guess:

- You are adding each item seperately to the store. In Sencha Touch this will eat up time. Better to create an array of items and add them at once.
- If you are adding items and the update of the store takes too long, stop sorting of the store.
- If you are interested in the list you better work with before and after events. Something like before updatedata and after updatadata. Or you could add start to the first itemTpl.

But again. Painting of a list which is infinite will not take any real time. So the DOM part really is not what you are looking for.

If you are using the dataview, this might be different.